# using div for css image- image not displaying on html

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Can anyone tell me why this image will not display? I'm using BBedit and the image is in the same folder as the index and style.

HTML:

```
<div class="imghome"></div>
```

CSS:

```
imghome{
    display: block;
    height: 300;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url("/pineapplenoir.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are just sitting in a single directory and you are not on a server then the path to the file probably doesn't need the slash.

```
imghome{
    display: block;
    height: 300;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url("pineapplenoir.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it was something other than that, ive used "." in front of imghome, ive also tried multiple variations of "/" "../" and having no "/"

Comment: if you inspect the element and look at the console output it should give an error message about the failed load.

Answer (score 0):

```
.imghome{
    display: block;
    height: 300;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url("pineapplenoir.jpg");
}
```

in css file while attempting to use styling for classes you have to use . infront of the classname in css file in order to styling to apply

Comment: Thanks, I'v tried a "." I've also tried no forward slash, also "../img/pineapplenoir"

Comment: is there anything else you can see that I am missing?

Comment: check the style page connection and also the file extension is correct or not?